# Not sure where to catch exception, validate, and message 'file is still processing'

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-services

Using C# built a Windows service to process .tif files coming in to server. The service works fine but throws an exception then continues to process the file as desired.  Problem is I am getting this error:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. at System.IO._*Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.*_Error.WinIOError() at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)

I believe I need to catch the exception, validate the error, and display a message "file is still processing" But, I'm not sure where?  My timer1 is set to 10 seconds, which should be plenty enough time to process files.

My code:

```
protected void timer1Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (mainProg == null)
            {
                mainProg = new ProcessFilesFromSource(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            }
            mainProg.ScanArchiverMain();          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("ScanArchiver Error", ex.ToString());
            EventLog.WriteEntry("ScanArchiver Online");
        }            
      }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("ScanArchiver Offline");
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are getting the exception inside the "scanArchiveMain" and it is swallowing the exception, you will not be able to catch it outside as where you have written the catch. you need to catch the exception inside the "ScanArchiveMain" function.

Comment: Maybe pause the timer while processing?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Timer while processing, and start it again when it's done.

Also take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) as an alternative for Timer.

```
protected void timer1Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        try
        {

            if (mainProg == null)
            {
                mainProg = new ProcessFilesFromSource(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            }
            mainProg.ScanArchiverMain();          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("ScanArchiver Error", ex.ToString());
            EventLog.WriteEntry("ScanArchiver Online");
        }            
        timer1.Start();
      }
```